# Copy-Item while avoiding links

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Is it possible to do a recursive copy while avoiding certain types of attributes? Or, possibly only include certain types of attributes? Specifically, Directories and Archives?

Thanks,
Henry

Edit:
This is for a script that copies only certain folders in a user profile. While doing a recursive copy, the script hits Documents and finds links to the special folders that I wanted to avoid. I tried the code below to no avail

```
$folders = @("Videos", "Music", "Saved Games", "Searches")
copy-item -path "C:\Users\UserName\*" -destination "\\remote\share\" -recurse -exclude $folders
```

Comment: You should look at the `Get-ChildItem` and `Copy-Item` cmdlets, and understand how the PowerShell pipe works. While `Copy-Item` does not appear to allow selecting by attribute, `Get-ChildItem` does, and you can pipe its results to `Copy-Item`.

Comment: As you were told copy-item has no attributes parameter, when using Get-ChildItem you have to use the -force Parameter to see ReparsePoints (aka junctions or links)  but that will also reveal files with Hidden and System attributes you might have to exclude also. See [this SuperUser question}(https://superuser.com/questions/528487/list-all-files-and-dirs-without-recursion-with-junctions) on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use the robocopy command instead of copy-item. The robocopy command has a /xjd switch that excludes junction points for directories.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question..

```
$from = "c:\temp\example\*" 
$to = "c:\temp\example\"  


Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Exclude *.zip
```

notice in the `$from` location I specified the path as `\*` at the end to indicate everything inside that directory.

then I can use Copy-Item `-Exclude` to specify what to exclude, `Copy-Item` also has a -Include parameter.

You could list your excludes in an array:

```
$from = "c:\temp\example\*" 
$to = "c:\temp\example\"  
$exclude = @('*.zip','*.7zip')

Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Exclude $exclude
```

You can find out more by typing the following into PowerShell:

```
Get-Help Copy-Item -Online
```

Comment: Hi, Will. Thanks for answering. I should mention that the issue I'm having is that I am trying to do a recursive copy on a user profile while avoiding directories like My Music, My Videos, etc. However, for some reason, while doing the copy on the Documents folder, the script finds these hidden links to these special folders that I would like to avoid. Which prompted my original question of whether it's possible to only copy Directories and Archives because I believe these links aren't considered either of the previous, unless I'm wrong...